# Possible to use Spring Boot 1.3.0.M1 with Spring Cloud?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

I'd like to be able to start using Spring Boot 1.3.0.M1 (and by extension Spring 4.2.0.RC1) along with Spring Cloud (config server, eureka, ribbon, feign, and zuul).

I'm using a gradle build, so initially I was using the dependencyManagement plugin like this:

```
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-parent:1.0.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT"
    }
}
```

But that means that no matter what version of spring boot I try to include, it gets overridden.

Instead I tried to manually include all the dependencies that the cloud starters include in the build and separately include spring boot 1.3.0.M1, but on server startup that leads to:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'servoMetricCollector' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/netflix/servo/ServoMetricsAutoConfiguration.class]
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/326) to support Spring Boot 1.3.0.

Comment: Thanks! Spring boot 1.3.0 really adds some nice stuff, looking forward to when it'll be able to integrate with spring cloud.